# Replace special character from a string in php

Tags: php

I have a string link this :

> "Special Word ±"

I want to replace the char `±` with `+-`.
I use `str_replace('±','+-',"Special Word ±")` but the result still shows:

> "Special Word ±"

Comment: Works fine: https://3v4l.org/PA1Wq You probably don't have the same characters.

Comment: What is the encoding of your php file and what is the encoding of your string? (are they exists in the same file or does the string come from some other source - other file/db/web request?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be a problem with PHP script file encoding. Try to convert your script encoding to for example "UTF8"

Comment: Thx..works
str_replace('±','+-',utf8_encode("Special Word ±"))